# Webview inside LinearLayout inside ScrollView doesnt show

Tags: java, android, android-webview

My layout:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dip"
    android:background="@drawable/feed_bg_newnew"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/header"
        layout="@layout/info_header" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/myWebView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dip" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/imgAttachmentsRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        layout="@layout/attachemnts_thumbs_container"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/docAttachmentsContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        layout="@layout/document_attachments_thumbs_container"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/feedItemFooter"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/feed_row_footer" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Webview doesnt show, i am also not hiding it in code. All other views display correctly. 
If i click on a button that part of one include, the webview shows. Content for webView is loaded from string.

What could be wrong?

Comment: hey did you find a solution to this problem? Please post it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

the webview has it's own "scrollview" sistem. So when you have a long webpage, the webview creates the scrolls automatically
so it's not logic to put a scrollview for something that already has.
just put it outside and it will show fine.